# Flutter on Android - TextField loses text after return from 'Recent Apps'

Tags: android, flutter, textfield

Problem with this Flutter app (on Android):

I type text into the TextField. I press "Recent Apps" and return to this app. The text is gone.

But

- rotating the screen
- or pressing ENTER/RETURN before 'Recent Apps'

doesn't lose the text.

These Flutter sample apps show the same problem

- https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField-class.html#material.TextField.2
- https://github.com/iampawan/fluttercalculator
- https://github.com/mjohnsullivan/flutter-by-example/tree/master/03_text_field

Why ? What should I do to not lose the text in this situation ?

```
$ flutter --version
Flutter 1.12.13+hotfix.8 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 0b8abb4724 (3 weeks ago) • 2020-02-11 11:44:36 -0800
Engine • revision e1e6ced81d
Tools • Dart 2.7.0
```

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("TextField"),
        ),
        body: Center(child: TextField()),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.star),
          onPressed: () => {},
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Probably you must use SharedPreferences to save text input

Comment: Thank you. You mean android.content.SharedPreferences ? So even such a simple Flutter app would need platform-specific code ? Really disappointing :-(

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences

Comment: Which version of flutter are you using?

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to say. I added it to the problem statement.

Comment: @rstrelba . Thank you :-) I've just started with Flutter/Dart. It may take a while to see how to add this to my sample app

Comment: Take a look https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook

Comment: Yes, I will. Thank you sooo much @rstrelba

Answer (score 0):

you need to do

```
textField.setSaveEnabled(false)
```

it's a stupid bug by android

Comment: Thanks @LenaBru, but that's a method on Android View, not Flutter TextField. Right ? So how can I use it ?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/47628#issuecomment-576889475) is a fix for the problem. Thank you, [spiritinlife](https://github.com/spiritinlife).